# How to specify default value for a resource to be used in Xaml designer

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization, attributes, designer

I have a localized resource (as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249369/Advanced-WPF-Localization)) to represent the FlowDirection on a control and it's working great along all other localized strings and such.

Resources.designer.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Looks up a localized string similar to RightToLeft.
/// </summary>
public static string enumDirection {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("enumDirection", resourceCulture);
    }
}
```

Usage in Xaml:

```
<StackPanel FlowDirection="{Loc enumDirection}">
```

### Problem:

The only problem is I no longer can use designer because it shows this error message:

> **ArgumentException: '' is not a valid value for property 'FlowDirection'.**
>
> StackTrace
>   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
>   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
>   at Soheil.Common.Localization.LocalizedDependencyProperty.SetValue(Object value)
>   at Soheil.Common.Localization.LocalizedValue.UpdateValue()
>   at Soheil.Common.Localization.LocExtension.b__0(Object x)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
>
> **InnerException: None**

this didn't work:

```
public static string enumDirection {
    get {
        var tmp = ResourceManager.GetString("enumDirection", resourceCulture);
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp) ? "RightToLeft" : tmp;
    }
}
```

So I tried adding some attributes (EditorAttribute and DefaultValue) to let the designer know the default value of enumDirection in designer time. But I couldn't make it work.

How can I get rid of that error message?

Comment: `FlowDirection` is of type `FlowDirection` not of type `string`.

Comment: xaml converts string to FlowDirection. just in case I tried `public static FlowDirection enumDirection{...}` but it still gives me the same error.